# How is the full-wave bridge rectifier still functioning?

Tags: full-bridge

How is the rectifier still functioning when one of the lines is cut-off?

[image: Rectifier]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *How is the rectifier still functioning when one of the lines is
> cut-off?*

The waveform you are getting is half wave rectified and, this is the waveform you will get when one of the diodes is not connected: -

[image]

Comment: Yes, but how is it able to complete the circuit, in this given scenario?

Comment: Half wave rectification is via D4 and D3 @spinachpizza. D1 and D2 never conduct.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. Thank you.